# Selenium [functional tests] versus Cucumber DD

Tags: cucumber

Currently I have a GIT project where I have created an automation project using Selenium and TestNG as the framework. I'm using the page object pattern for my tests where it supports multi environment.

I would like to now implement cucumber tests

My question here is would it be wise to create a separate github poject or use the existing projects where selenium does functional tests and just create a separate package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had two separate projects and it was maintenance hassle. Update changes in both frameworks. The benefit being they served different testing phases and maintained by different teams.

You can either create a third project containing pageobjects and common functions to be imported separately in the Cucumber as well as Selenium project or keep under the same project.

Comment: Thanks that actually makes sense !!